# Data does not show in VR with sqlite database

Tags: sql, sqlite, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

i have a highscore table for my VR Oculus rift and i want to save data to sqlite database and display the data from the VR Headset but however only unity is able to display the data from database to the highscore board, the VR headset does not even show any data from the database when i import the game from unity to the oculus rift.

Here are my following code to display the score and it only works inside unity but not the vr headset:

```
 private void GetScores()
    {
        highScores.Clear();


            using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                dbConnection.Open();

                Debug.Log("DB Step 1");
                using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    Debug.Log("DB Step 2");
                    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM highscoresss";
                    dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                    using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        Debug.Log("DB Step 3");
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Debug.Log("DB Step 4");
                            highScores.Add(new HighScore(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2)));


                        }
                        Debug.Log("DB Step 5");
                        dbConnection.Close();
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }


    }
void Start()
    {
        connectionString = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/mydatabasess.db";
        ChangingText.text = connectionString;
        ShowScores();
    }
```

I use Andriodlog the capture the error and it keep saying error connecting the DB:sqlite3

Error Message androidlog for vr Oculus rift:

[image: Error Message androidlog for vr Oculus rift]

Highscore table with data in unity:
[image: Highscore table with data in unity]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with database path; are you altering it for your Android build?
Streaming assets are usually copied by Unity to a specific location, [accessible through different means depending on the platform](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html). If i were you, for debugging purposes I would check if your database file is where you expect it.

```
if (!File.Exists(yourDatabasePath))
    Debug.Log("Couldn't locate database at {0}",yourDatabasePath);
```

If this ends up to be the culprit, it is probably easier to either use the [streamingAssetsPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) or just copy your database into persistent storage on device and then access it normally through a new path, which would be defined for your Oculus build like that:

```
string yourDatabasePath = 
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    "Assets/StreamingAssets/mydatabasess.db";
#else
    "sdcard/MyAppFolder/mydatabasess.db"; //just an example
#endif
```